# Execute shell script from sqlplus prompt and exit sqlplus if shell script fails

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I am executing shell script from sqlplus console that checks for file and if file is not present it fails with exit code 1. Though, shell script fails, sqlplus doesn't exit and it starts running next scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Can you amend your shell script?  Have it let SQL Plus know the resultant state, eg

```
Shell
=====
Does normal work.
if [ shell level error ] then
  echo "pro File not found" > /tmp/sqlplus.status
  echo "exit" >> /tmp/sqlplus.status
else
  echo "pro Continuing on" > .status
fi

SQL Plus
========
host my_shell.sh
@/tmp/sqlplus.status
```